# How I can extract a subset of years from a NetCDF file (e.g. to use in cell statistics)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, netcdf, climate

I want to use 5 years of data from a netCDF with 10 years of data (monthly slices). I saw this tutorial video that mentions this, but I can't figure out how to select more than one time slice.

http://video.arcgis.com/watch/2108/analyzing-netcdf-data-using-arcmap

Answer (score 2):

For working with NetCDF files, I like to write a small python program and process the data there.  In the example below, I compute the average precipitation over several months using python, then pass the resulting product as a raster to ArcMap.

This example also illustrates accessing NetCDF data remotely using OPeNDAP, which allows you to just extract the data you need from a remote URL without downloading the entire file. But since NetCDF4-Python works with remote OPeNDAP URLs just the same as local NetCDF files, you can just replace that with a local NetCDF filename also.

You can run this example in ArcMap 10.1 or higher. First install the free [ESRI Multidimensional Supplemental Tools](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9f963f362fe5417f87d44618796db938).  Then open a Python prompt (Multiprocessing=>Python), paste the code below, and hit enter twice.

You should get this:[image]

Here's the code, also [here on github](https://github.com/rsignell-usgs/dap2arc/blob/master/src/prism2raster.py)

```py
''' extract historical climate data from PRISM based on 
    bounding box and lat/lon range
'''
import os
import netCDF4
import numpy as np
import arcpy
import datetime

# mean precip over specified bounding box, start and stop time
def mean_precip(nc,bbox=None,start=None,stop=None):
    lon=nc.variables['lon'][:]
    lat=nc.variables['lat'][:]
    tindex0=netCDF4.date2index(start,nc.variables['time'],select='nearest')
    tindex1=netCDF4.date2index(stop,nc.variables['time'],select='nearest')
    bi=(lon>=box[0])&(lon<=box[2])
    bj=(lat>=box[1])&(lat<=box[3])
    p=nc.variables['precip_mean'][tindex0:tindex1,bj,bi]
    latmin=np.min(lat[bj])
    p=np.mean(p,axis=0)
    lon=lon[bi]
    lat=lat[bj]
    return p,lon,lat

url='http://geoport.whoi.edu/thredds/dodsC/prism3/monthly'
box = [-102,36.5,-101,37]  # Bounding box for Texas County, Oklahoma
nc=netCDF4.Dataset(url)
z,lon,lat=mean_precip(nc,bbox=box,start=datetime.datetime(1936,11,1,0,0),stop=datetime.datetime(1937,4,1,0,0))
latmin=np.min(lat)
lonmin=np.min(lon)
latmin=np.min(lat)
dx=np.diff(lon)
dy=np.diff(lat)
# check if dx or dy vary by more than one percent
assert np.abs(np.ptp(dx)/np.mean(dx))<=0.01,'longitude spacing is not uniform'
assert np.abs(np.ptp(dy)/np.mean(dy))<=0.01,'latitude spacing is not uniform'
if dy[0]>0:  # lat increasing
    z=np.array(z[::-1,:])
if dx[0]<0:  # lon decreasing
    z=np.array(z[:,::-1])    
dx=np.abs(np.mean(dx))
dy=np.abs(np.mean(dy))
xyOrig = arcpy.Point(float(lonmin),float(latmin))

# create Arc Raster
arcpy.workspace  = "C:\\workspace"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
rasterName = "precip"
outRaster = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(arcpy.workspace,rasterName))
grid1=arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(z,xyOrig,dx,dy)
grid1.save(os.path.join(arcpy.workspace,outRaster))
strPrj = "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID"\
         "['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],"\
         "UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]"
arcpy.DefineProjection_management(outRaster,strPrj)
print "Written: %s" % grid1
arcpy.AddMessage("Written: %s" % grid1)
```